# system.xml field dependency

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, system.xml

So you can set in the `system.xml` file of a module a dependency between fields by adding a `<depends>` tag in one of the fields.

```
<field1>
    ....
</field1>
<field2>
    ....
    <depends>
       <field1>1</field1>
    </depends>
</field2>
```

The code above means that `field2` will be shown when the value of `field1` is `1`. 
I want to know how/if can I tell Magento to show `field2` if the value for `field1` is `1` OR `2`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
<depends>
    <field separator="|">
        <value>1|2|3</value>
    </field>
</depends>
```

Comment: Do you know that this works, or are you just putting it out there?

Comment: Dude...I don't know how, but this actually works. Now I'm ashamed and sorry for all my bad words I said to the guys that implemented the config section. For some reason `$dependent['separator']` returns the value of the attribute `separator`. To whom ever downvoted this, please upvote (twice if possible). Works perfectly. Thanks. cc @benmarks

Comment: This working != it being a good idea. I think there's no need to apologize for your words :-D

Comment: verrrrrry cool! This appears to also be working in Magento 2.

Answer (score 7):

**[EDIT]**

I was wrong in my answer below. I will not delete it (yet) because I got 7 upvotes on this :). But I'm editing it so you all have the chance to retract your vote (even downvote it, because I deserve it).

**Original Answer**

Ha!..I found it.
**Short answer:** You cannot!
**Long answer**: You should be able to do it if someone would have known the difference between an array and an object.
In theory this should work

```
<field1>
    ....
</field1>
<field2>
    ....
    <depends>
       <field1>
           <value>1|2</value>
           <separator>|</separator>
       </field1>
    </depends>
</field2>
```

But in the code that handles the dependency, `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form::initFields` around line 366 there is this code

```
if (isset($dependent['separator'])) {
    $dependentValue = explode((string)$dependent['separator'], $dependentValue);
}
```

`$dependent` is always an object so `$dependent['separator']` is never set.
If I change the code above to

```
if (isset($dependent->separator)) {
    $dependentValue = explode((string)$dependent->separator, $dependentValue);
}
```

everything works smoothly.
I guess I cannot change the core just for the sake of an extension so I have to create 2 fields instead of 1, one for each value from `field1` or create a custom js that handles this and add it to the config page.

Comment: Damn it. I know this kind of bugs :-) I hope you reported it? Great insight!

Comment: Oh man that is some great investigation are you sure you are not Sherlock? +1 for reporting it.

Comment: @DavidManners elementary my dear watson

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked under Magento 1 but since I landed here looking for an example for Magento 2 and the answers here pointed me in the right direction, here is a working example tested in Magento 2.4.4 in case it helps anyone else:

```
<field id="time" translate="label comment" type="time" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
<label>Start Time</label>
<depends>
    <field id="frequency" separator="|">D|W|M</field>
</depends>
```

There is also a `negative` parameter that can be used to tailor the condition even more.
[image]