# Widget.xml depends on multi value

Tags: xml, widget

There are some post to discuss depends on multi-value for system.xml, [(https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9935/system-xml-field-dependency)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9935/system-xml-field-dependency)

Below example come from Magento Core Code(app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/system.xml

```
<depends>
    <order_status separator=",">processing,processed_ogone</order_status>
</depends>
```

I have tested this feature for system.xml, it works, but it is not work for widget.xml can anyone tell me how to do "depends on multi-value" for widget.xml?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I stumbled on the same problem and here's a solution :

```
            <depends>
                <order_status>
                    <values>
                        <value1>processing</value1>
                        <value2>processed_ogone</value2>
                    </values>
                </order_status>
            </depends>
```

I hope this can help someone.

Comment: This is invalid in widget.xml and causes parsing errors.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the post which you linked, the separator functionality works because it is defined in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form::initFields()`. As widget config files are *not* parsed by this class, I doubt this will work.